# How to use the GitHub Actions `workflow_run` event?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

> Another frequently-requested feature for Actions is a way to trigger one workflow based on the completion of another workflow. For example, you may want to take the results of a CI workflow and run some further analysis.
>
> The new workflow_run event enables you to trigger a new workflow when one or more workflows are requested or completed. Runs triggered by the workflow_run event always use the default branch for the repository, and have access to a read/write token as well as secrets. As an **example**, as a maintainer you could set up a workflow that takes the artifacts generated by the pull request workflow, do some analysis, and post comments back to the pull request.  This event is also available as a webhook and works all repos.

This is quoted from [Github's blog](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/).

Could anybody tell me how to implement the **example** proposed using the new event `workflow_run`? The documentation only provide a very simple example:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Run Tests"]
    branches: [main]
    types: 
      - completed
      - requested
```

I would be very glad if someone can teach me how to achieve the example.

Comment: Can't answer but basically asked the same question in the GH community at https://github.community/t/workflow-run-not-triggered/144999

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To get the example to work (i.e. to have one workflow wait for another to complete) you need two files. Both files live in the `.github/workflows` folder of a repository.

The first file would be set up as usual. This file will be triggered by whatever event(s) are set in the `on` section:

```yaml
---
name: Preflight

on:
  - pull_request
  - push

jobs:
  preflight-job:
    name: Preflight Step
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: env
```

The second file states that it should only trigger `on` the `workflow_run` event for any `workflows` with the name `Preflight`:

```yaml
---
name: Test

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - Preflight
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  test-job:
    name: Test Step
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: env
```

This more-or-less the same as [the example from the GitHub Actions manual](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run).

As you can see on [the actions page](https://github.com/potherca-blog/github-actions-workflow_run-event/actions)
of [my example repo](https://github.com/potherca-blog/github-actions-workflow_run-event), the Preflight workflow will run first. After it has completed, the Test workflow will be triggered:

[image: Screenshot of workflows screen]

As you can *also* see, the **branch** does not appear for the "Test" workflow.

This is because, (quoting from the manual):

[image: Screenshot of caveat in the manual]

> This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file is on the default branch.

This means that the "Test" workflow will run on/with the code from the default branch (usually `main` or `master`).

There is a workaround for this...

Every actions is run with a set of [contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions). The `github` context holds information about the event that triggered the workflow. This includes the branch that the event was originally triggered from/for: `github.event.workflow_run.head_branch`.

This can be used to check out the origination branch in the action, using the [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action provided by GitHub.

To do this, the Yaml would be:

```yaml
---
name: Test

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - Preflight
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  test-job:
    name: Test Step
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
      - run: git branch
      - run: env
```

Comment: I'm confused by this: in your example it appears you're using `main` which I can guess is your default branch. What if I want to trigger `workflow_run` i.e. "Test" on a PR and have "Test" run on my PR branch? (This is useful in cases where I want to e.g. run tests and then deploy to a preview environment.)

Comment: @maxcountryman "Preflight" has `on` set to `pull_request`, which means it will be triggered by a PR. As "Test" is dependant on "Preflight", it will also be triggered for that PR... [as you can see here](https://github.com/potherca-blog/github-actions-workflow_run-event/pull/1)

Comment: With the Preflight.yml on a branch 'staging', the Preflight workflow will use the 'staging' branch code. What about the test workflow on 'main'? It will use the 'main' branch code? Or will use the 'staging' branch code?

Comment: @CarlosFagianiJr **Now** I understand what you and maxcountryman mean  I've updated my answer to explain about how the branching works (and how to deal with it).

Comment: @maxcountryman I think I misunderstood your comment before, I've updated my answer regarding branches. Does this answer your query regarding branches?

Comment: @Potherca, if I have workflows A and B, and want to add another workflow C which should start when both A and B have finished. Is it possible?

Comment: @Stqs I think that would make an excellent [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to ask... Not that much room to answer details here in the comments.

Comment: @Potherca thanks a lot. About context, is that possible to get the labels of the Pull Request which triggered the "parent" workflow (Preflight) from the "child" workflow (Test)?

Comment: @Guts I think it might be better to ask your question as a new one. You could link to it from here, so I can take a look at it...

Comment: @Potherca where is the documentation for `head_branch` or indeed, any list of the properties generated by the `workflow_run` events? I can't find them documented anywhere

Comment: @Segfault Ah, yes. Welcome to the jungle known as "GitHub Docs"! The docs you are looking for are in the [Webhook events and payloads](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#workflow_run).

Comment: To get there you would start at the ["`github` context" section of "Context and expression syntax for GitHub Actions"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context), which links to [the `workflow_run` section of "Events that trigger workflows"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run), which in turn links to [the "workflow_run" section of "Webhook events and payloads"](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#workflow_run) 

Comment: the example payload in that document doesn't actually have an example of the workflow_run object, and instead it just says that it shares many of the same properties as a "check_suite"... many but not all? which are which? it's a mystery.

Comment: There is a comment on the GitHub Docs issue tracker that actually lists them all: https://github.com/github/docs/issues/4612#issuecomment-856182852

Comment: Yeah, I ran like 150 jobs with a lot of logging and dumping whilst figuring out how everything works. 

Comment: Do the invoking and the called workflows need to be on the same repo?

Comment: They do not _need_ to be in the same repo, but if they are not, other things come into play (for instance GitHub Reusable Workflows and various permissions/settings).

Comment: Why we need git branch after checkout?

Comment: @pyang If we do not checkout a specific branch, by default, the workflow will run on the default branch (usually `main` or `master`).

Comment: @Potherca When creating this workflow for the first time, via a PR? The workflow does not seem to be picked up in the PR, is it expected ?

Comment: @Brice without further details that question is impossible to answer... Might be better to open a new queston here on stackoverflow to ask. It could have to do with branches or [workflow approval](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks) or any number of things...

Comment: I came up with the conclusion that workflows triggered by `workflow_run` can only work on the main branch as you mentioned in your answer, so they cannot run in a PR. Regardless thank you for reaching back !

Comment: `workflow_run` is such a disappointing feature. Even with the workaround the workflow doesn't appear on commits/branch, so can't be used for PR checks etc. Seems GH want us merging all jobs into one massive yml file. Wish there was a way to define jobs in separate files!